# Python JSON data parsing

Tags: python, json, api, data-partitioning

Im trying to get the average of "active" for each place under a specific area. So say the output would be ("Andaman and Nicobar Islands": 10, "Andhra Pradesh": 12) however i get type error string indices must be integers from the "r[v["recovered"]].append(v["deceased"])"

```
import requests, json
from collections import defaultdict
from statistics import mean

# request and parse the data
response_API = requests.get("https://data.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json").json()

def get_mean_active(response_API):
    r = defaultdict(list)
    for v in response_API.values():
        r[v["area"]].append(v["active"])
    return {k: mean(v) for k, v in r}


print(
    get_mean_active(
        response_API["Andaman and Nicobar Islands"]["districtData"]["top level here"]
    )
)
```

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
PS C:\Users\e\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\test>  c:; cd 'c:\Users\e\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\test'; & 'C:\User  File "C:\Users\e\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 268, in run_path    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\e\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\e\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\e\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\test\ex2.py", line 19, in <module>
    get_mean_active(
  File "c:\Users\e\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\test\ex2.py", line 14, in get_mean_active
    r[v["Andaman and Nicobar Islands"]].append(v["active"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
PS C:\Users\e\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\test>
```

Comment: If this code works, why are you here?  If not, explain the *specifics* of the problem.

Comment: @ScottHunter it doesnt work i cant seem to pull the specific data to form the desired output, im currently getting Typerror: string indices must be integers.

Comment: I get a different error. There exists no `r[v["recovered"]].append(v["deceased"])` in the provided code. Please post the actual code and a full stack trace.

Comment: @MichaelRuth Sorry about that, my mistake. now ive updated it to what it should be.

Comment: What is `top level here`? I don't see that in the JSON. Are you replacing that with a district name?

Comment: I don't think you need that at all. I think you want to loop over all the districts, not the values in a single district. The values are integers and strings, not dictionaries.

Comment: But what is `v["area"]` supposed to be? I don't see that in the JSON.

Comment: The error originates in `get_mean_price_by_submodel` but the code includes only `get_mean_active`. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the associated stack trace.

Comment: @Barmar yes exactly its a place holder for the district name,  interesting. So in the "top level here" would go district data and at that do i need to use json.dumps? "v["area]" is supposed to take the district name.

Comment: @MichaelRuth again mistake on my part, traceback is updated and everything is as it should be. Currently getting error "r[v["Andaman and Nicobar Islands"]].append(v["active"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Comment: I don't understand why you're calling `mean()`. Each area only has one element in the district data, so the mean is the same as the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument you're passing is going too deep into the nested dictionaries. You want to pass the entire `districtData` dictionary to `get_mean_active()`, not a specific area. Then the function loops over all the areas.

The loop should use `.items()`, not `.values()`, because the area name is the key of each dictionary element, not an element of the nested dictionary.

And the dictionary comprehension at the end needs to use `r.items()`.

```
import requests, json
from collections import defaultdict
from statistics import mean

# request and parse the data
response_API = requests.get("https://data.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json").json()

def get_mean_active(response_API):
    r = defaultdict(list)
    for area, v in response_API.items():
        r[area].append(v["active"])
    return {k: mean(v) for k, v in r.items()}


print(
    get_mean_active(
        response_API["Andaman and Nicobar Islands"]["districtData"]
    )
)
```

Result:

```
{'Nicobars': 0, 'North and Middle Andaman': 0, 'South Andaman': 19, 'Unknown': -13}
```

Comment: Very much appreciate your assistance @Barmar the reason i used mean was because i was going through a level up from your code. So say,  the results from your output would all be in one key {"Andaman and Nicobar Islands": 6},  {"Andhra Pradesh": 1227 } getting the area and the average to all witin the area.

Comment: But you're calling the function on just `Andaman and Nicobar Islands`. It seems like you should be calculating the mean outside the function, when you loop over the districts.

Comment: Or maybe you just need `return mean(v['active'] for v in response_API.values())`

Comment: Currenlty trying those approaches, this has been a great help.